# Camera moving down

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on Unity and I have already set how to smoothly move up camera when player get on higher position. But if player is on position which is below on camera, then you lost " life ". I need a way to show score and highscore but on way that when you lost " life ", camera is moving down.

For better explanation you can see how look like lost " life " on Doodle Jump game. youtu.be/wjofzwaC_Oo?t=18m30s , did you catch how he lost life and how camera move? I need that move ;)

This is my code which I used to move camera higher during game and it's attached to MainCamera.

```
void Update () 
    {
        playerHeightY = player.position.y;

        if (playerHeightY > platCheck) 
        {
            PlatformManager ();
        }
        float currentCameraHeight = transform.position.y;
        float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp (currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY, Time.deltaTime * 100f);

        if (playerHeightY > currentCameraHeight) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
        } 

        else 
        {
            if (playerHeightY<(currentCameraHeight-5f))
                {   
                   SceneManager.LoadScene("Scena1");
                }
        }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your code `if (playerHeightY<(currentCameraHeight-5f))` is a check to see if the player has fallen off the screen, below the view of the camera. In this case, you do not want to hard code in `5f` because you may later want the change the size of your camera viewport.

Instead, change the entire inside of your `else` statement to the following:

```
Camera cameraComp = this.GetComponent<Camera>();
Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cameraComp);
if (!(GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, player.collider.bounds)))
{
    // handle death
}
```

This checks to see if the bounding box of the player is within the view of the camera. If the player is NOT in view of the camera, we handle the death. A note: this will also kill the player if he moves off the left or right of the screen. If you just want death off the bottom of the screen, you need to check if the player has fallen towards the bottom frustum plane. Comment on this answer if you would like help with that.

Now, onto your question, it's actually a lot easier than you think. If you want camera movement exactly like Doodle Jump, all you need to do is set the camera to interpolate to one screen length lower than the bottom of your camera's view INSTEAD of to the player's height:

```
bool died = false; // PUT THIS OUTSIDE OF YOUR UPDATE FUNCTION

...  

else
{
    Camera cameraComp = this.GetComponent<Camera>();
    Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cameraComp);
    if (!(GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, player.collider.bounds)))
    {

        float currentCameraHeight = transform.position.y;

        if (!died)
            float finalCameraHeight = currentCameraHeight - (currentCameraHeight - playerHeightY);

        float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp (currentCameraHeight, finalCameraHeight, Time.deltaTime * 200f);

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
        died = true;
    }
}
```

This finds the distance from the current camera height to the fallen player, then moves the camera down far enough to where the player is falling from the top of the screen like doodle jump.

This should work and yes I know the code is really ugly but I'm at work right now so I didn't want to post any solutions that may not work because I can't test. Comment on this if something doesn't work and I'll try to help.

Comment: Firstly, big thanks for your help bro :). I put the code but I have problems. Errors are: Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(56,58): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(UnityEngine.Camera)' has some invalid arguments

Second error: Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(56,58): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `GameManager' expression to type `UnityEngine.Camera'

http://oi66.tinypic.com/w1bp4x.jpg

My script is named GameManager. If you want I can send you whole script to your mail, of course, if you can :)

Comment: I think I know how to fix this. I believe the argument should be a component, not the camera in its entirety. I edited the answer code to show how to fix. Let me know if this still doesn't work.

Comment: There are no errors, while playing error are null reference to player. I checked I nothing is missing. Error is this : but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Collider to the game object "Player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.Collider.get_bounds ()
GameManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:58)
And warning : warning CS0219: The variable `newHeightOfCamera1' is assigned but its value is never used

Unity automatically changed player bounds player.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds)))

Comment: @dikario Lol I completely forgot to modify the camera's position. Okay, I added that line of code (the `transform.position = ...`). Also, just add a collider component to your player.

Comment: @dikario If you really really don't want to add a collider I *believe* it's also possible to get an AABB from the renderer of the object as such: `player.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;`

Comment: Hey :) Well done! And thanks a thousand times :) If you want cooperation or something feel free to contact me for anything dario.karin95@gmail.com :) Thanks

Comment: @dikario Glad I could help. I'll save you email for a future project. I'm working on a few things at the moment though.

Comment: Thank you! Don't worry, I have thousands ideas and you will find. Kind regards and all best for future projects! :)